# Javascript form validation still submits form when null data inputted

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a simple form in HTML that submits data to Microsoft CDS using javascript. The form submits fine.

I wanted to put in some validation to ensure that fields must be completed (no empty fields) so I used javascript form validation. I have only done validation on the first two fields: Title and First Name.

The validation works to the extent that a message pops up saying "The title must not be empty" and "The first name must not be empty" - BUT... the form still submits!

I think the problem is that I'm using two separate Scripts, one to run the validation and one to submit the data. How do I combine the two?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Contact Us</title>
        
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        
        <! -- JQUERY LINK -->
        <script src="jq.min.js"></script>

        <style>
            body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
            * {box-sizing: border-box;}

            input, select, textarea {
              width: 100%;
              padding: 12px;
              border: 1px solid #ccc;
              border-radius: 4px;
              box-sizing: border-box;
              margin-top: 6px;
              margin-bottom: 16px;
              resize: vertical;
            }

            button {
              background-color: #04AA6D;
              color: white;
              padding: 12px 20px;
              border: none;
              border-radius: 4px;
              cursor: pointer;
            }

            button:hover {
              background-color: #45a049;
            }

            .container {
              border-radius: 5px;
              background-color: #f2f2f2;
              padding: 20px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            function validateform(){  
            var title=document.myform.Title.value;  
            var firstname=document.myform.FirstName.value;  
              
            if (title==null || title==""){  
              alert("Title can't be blank");  
              return false;  
            }else if (firstname==null || firstname==""){  
              alert("Firstname can't be blank.");  
              return false;  
              }  
            }  
        </script> 
    
        <h3>Contact Form to submit to SP List</h3>

        <! -- HTML FORM BELOW -->
        <div class="container">
            <form name="myform" onsubmit="return validateform()">
            <! -- HTML INPUT -->
            <label>Title</label>
            <input type="text" id="Title" placeholder="Your title...">
          
            <label>First Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="FirstName" placeholder="Your forename..">

            <label>Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="LastName" placeholder="Your surname..">
            
            <label>Date</label><br>
            <input type="date" id="Date" placeholder="Your surname..">  
            
            <label>Country</label>
            <select id="Country">
              <option value="England">England</option>
              <option value="Wales">Wales</option>
              <option value="Scotland">Scotland</option>
            </select>

            <label>Message</label>
            <textarea id="Message" placeholder="Write something.." style="height:200px"></textarea>

            <! -- HTML SUBMISSION -->
            <button id="btn_submit">Submit</button>
            <input id="postResult" type="text" value="Submission status: Awaiting submission" readonly>
            </form>
        </div>

        <! -- JS BELOW --> 
        <script>
            $(function () {
                $("#btn_submit").click(function () {
                    
                    var formData = { 
                        Title: $("#Title").val(), 
                        FirstName: $("#FirstName").val(), 
                        LastName: $("#LastName").val(),
                        Message: $("#Message").val(), 
                        Country: $("#Country").val(), 
                        Date: $("#Date").val() 
                    };
                    
                    $.ajax({
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    type: "POST",
                        url: "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
                        data: JSON.stringify(formData),
                    success: function () {
                        $("#postResult").val("Submission status: Success");
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        $("#postResult").val("Submission status: Failed");
                    }
                });
                });
                
                
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you are not using a submit button to submit the form, you are using a regular button that launches an AJAX POST when clicked, and you are trying to stop the form from submitting using `onsubmit`.

In order to not submit the form you either should use the default form POST with an input submit button, and return false to `onsubmit`. Or call the validation when the button is clicked and if it passes the validation then call the AJAX method. Don't call the AJAX method like `$("#btn_submit").click(function ())` as this will happen and you cant prevent it once the user clicks the button, you should instead call the validation and with an `if` you either call the AJAX method or not.

With your code it would be like:

```
    <! -- JS BELOW --> 
    <script>
    
        function validateForm(){  
        var title=document.myform.Title.value;  
        var firstname=document.myform.FirstName.value;  
          
        if (title==null || title==""){  
          alert("Title can't be blank");  
          return false;  
        }else if (firstname==null || firstname==""){  
          alert("Firstname can't be blank.");  
          return false;  
        }else{
          return true;     
        }
        }  

    
        $(function () {
            $("#btn_submit").click(function () {
            
                if(validateForm()){
                
                var formData = { 
                    Title: $("#Title").val(), 
                    FirstName: $("#FirstName").val(), 
                    LastName: $("#LastName").val(),
                    Message: $("#Message").val(), 
                    Country: $("#Country").val(), 
                    Date: $("#Date").val() 
                };
                
                $.ajax({
                contentType: 'application/json',
                type: "POST",
                    url: "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
                    data: JSON.stringify(formData),
                success: function () {
                    $("#postResult").val("Submission status: Success");
                },
                error: function () {
                    $("#postResult").val("Submission status: Failed");
                }
            });
                }
            });
            
            
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: "Or call the validation when the button is clicked and if it passes the validation then call the AJAX method." - how do I go about doing this?

Comment: @DrHY I updated my answer with the code as example. Check how firstly i put the code in the same <script> tag and then in the validation method I return true if it has no errors. Then in the function triggered by clicking the button there's an `if(validateForm())` that will only submit the form if it returns true (has passed the validation)

Answer (score 1):

Amend the `validateform` function as follow:

```js
function validateform(){
  let invalid = false

  // Do the validation here. assign invalid to true if any field is invalid

  if (invalid) {
    window.event.preventDefault() // Prevent the default form submit behavior
  } else {
    // Your form submission ajax logic here...
  }
}
```

And remove the second script block since the logic has already been embedded into the above `validateform` function.

Comment: You don't need the preventDefault as it is not a form with a submit it is a button calling an AJAX POST request

Comment: The `btn_submit` button is inside a form element. The `type` of a button inside a form element is defaulted to `submit` which submit the form when click ([`type` Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-type)).

Comment: Didn't know that the type of a button by default would be submit. Nice, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the validadeteform()  and put all logic into the callback function.

- Remove onsubmit on your form. It should be like this:

```html
<form name="myform">
```

- Change button to input type, something like this:

```html
<input type="button" id="btn_submit" value="Submit" />
```

- The callback function called when you click #btn_submit should look like this:

```js
$(function () {
                    $("#btn_submit").click(function () {

                        var formData = {
                            Title: $("#Title").val(),
                            FirstName: $("#FirstName").val(),
                            LastName: $("#LastName").val(),
                            Message: $("#Message").val(),
                            Country: $("#Country").val(),
                            Date: $("#Date").val()
                        };

                        if (formData.Title == "" || formData.FirstName == "") {
                            alert("Title and Firstname can't be blank");
                        } else {
                            $.ajax({
                                contentType: 'application/json',
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
                                data: JSON.stringify(formData),
                                success: function () {
                                    $("#postResult").val("Submission status: Success");
                                },
                                error: function () {
                                    $("#postResult").val("Submission status: Failed");
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                });
```